# Invalid sample rate While recording an audio

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I have two microphones [Blue microphone - snow ball ice](https://www.bluedesigns.com/products/snowball-ice/) and Stage line microphone ([EMG-500P](https://www.img-stageline.com/products/pa-technology/microphones-and-headphones/gooseneck-microphones/emg-500p/), [DMS-1 microphone base](https://www.monacor.com/products/pa-technology/microphones-and-headphones/microphone-accessories/dms-1/), [MPR-1 pre-amp](https://www.img-stageline.com/products/audio-tools/preamplifiers/splitters-and-transformers/mpr-1/), [soundcard](https://sandberg.it/en-gb/categories/audio/soundcards) as shown in the image below).

I am using a [python sound device library example from git](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/0.3.7/examples/rec_unlimited.py) and i working fine. Audio recording from Blue microphone is working fine for many different sampling rate like 16000, 44100, 48000 etc (-r = 16000/44100/48000) but Stage line microphone is recording audio only when sampling rate are 44100 or 48000 Hz. Any sampling rate other than 44100/48000 Hz its throwing an error.

> PortAudioError: Error opening InputStream: Invalid sample rate
>   [PaErrorCode -9997]

How can i record at 16KHz from Stage line microphone ?
Why am I not able to sample at 16kHz ? Is it because of sound card ?

I am using [sound device python example](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/0.3.12/examples/rec_unlimited.py) exact code to record both from Blue microphone and Stage line microphone.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The problem won't be with the mic or pre-amp as these are just analogue processors.  How are you opening the input stream and what other parameters are you specifying for audio format?

Comment: I am using Sound device python example for both the devices mentioned.(https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/0.3.12/examples/rec_unlimited.py) . I updated the question as well.